How to preserve newlines inside of JSX tags in TSX TypeScript?
I would like to use TSX for Markdown rendering, the problem - TypeScript TSX Compiler strips newlines and it breaks the markdown.
The example below would output text as Some text. - list item a - list item b with newlines removed, playground.
Is it possible to somehow prevent it?
const React = {
  createElement(tag: any, attrs: any, ...children: any[]): any {
    return console.log(JSON.stringify({ tag, attrs, children }))
  }
};

<markdown>
  Some text.

  - list item a
  - list item b
</markdown>

P.S.
Maybe it would be possible to do with TypeScript Compiler Options like Transformers etc? Something like - intercept the source loading and replace the \n in text in JSX tags with say __NL__\n, so, it will be possible to restore the newlines by replacing __NL__ back with \n during the Markdown rendering stage?
Or maybe it's possible to do it for specific engine bun.js with some custom API?

What about CSS? white-space

@Harrison I don't understand, the newlines will be stripped from the text before it will be passed to Markdown renderer. So it doesn't matter what's set in CSS.

The whitespace can be preserved in the JS side with Template literals, then preserved through to render from there

I'm not entirely certain this is what you're after, but let's discuss...
I believe what you're after can be achieved with Template literals and CSS white-space: pre-wrap.
It doesn't seem to be a TypeScript compiler issue, more the fact that HTML compresses whitespace based on the compression algorithm.
Note that new lines are normally compressed:

Table directly from MDN
Solution:
white-space: pre-wrap
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {

  const markdown = `  Some text.

  - list item a
  - list item b
  - this is a really long piece of text that should wrap when given the chance to do so. You may need to adjust the size of the window to test this theory out!
  `
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {markdown}
    </div>
  );
}

body {
  background: white;
}

.App {
  color: black;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

Playground Link


var text = `  Some text.

  - list item a
  - list item b
  - this is a really long piece of text that should wrap when given the chance to do so. You may need to adjust the size of the window to test this theory out!
  `;

document.getElementById("element").innerText = text
#element {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
<div id="element"></div>



Alternatively
You could use a package such as React-Markdown, as it may be easier to implement, see their demo.
Other packages exist too, this is just one example of many packages that could be used.
import React from 'react'
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client'
import Markdown from 'react-markdown'

const markdown = '# Hi, *Pluto*!'

createRoot(document.body).render(<Markdown>{markdown}</Markdown>)

